# When overloading greater than operator to compare two double values from different classes, I am getting a operand error

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, logical-operators, friend-function

I am working on a homework assignment to:

1. Add the area of 2 circles using an overloaded +
2. Add the area of 2 rectangles using an overloaded +
3. Compare the area of a circle and rectangle to see if they are the same using overloaded ==
4. Compare the area of a circle and rectangle to see which is bigger using overloaded >

So far I have completed the first three. I have written code for the greater than function overload, but I keep getting an error stating - "no operator ">" matches these operands"

I have tried changing the operator function to be a member function of class rectangle and class circle. I have even tried changing the > operator to other operators but I still have the same error.

ShapesType.h selection-

```
    friend bool operator==(const circleType&,
    const rectangleType&);
//Overload the operator ==

    friend bool operator>(const circleType&,
    const rectangleType&);
//Overload the operator >
```

ShapesTypeImp.cpp selection-

```
    bool operator== (const circleType& Circle,
    const rectangleType& rectangle)
    {
          return Circle.area() == rectangle.area();
    }

    bool operator> (const circleType& Circle,
    const rectangleType& rectangle)
    {
          return (Circle.area() > rectangle.area());
    }
```

Main.cpp selection-

```
                case 3:
            cout << "Enter the radius of the circle: ";
            cin >> radius;

            while (cin.fail())
            {
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(100, '\n');
                cout << endl << "Not a valid input, enter a number: ";
                cin >> radius;
            }

            cout << "Enter the height of the rectangle: ";
            cin >> height;

            while (cin.fail())
            {
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(100,'\n');
                cout << endl << "Not a valid input, enter a number: ";
                cin >> height;
            }

            cout << "Enter the width of the rectangle: ";
            cin >> width;

            while (cin.fail())
            {
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(100,'\n');
                cout << endl << "Not a valid input, enter a number: ";
                cin >> width;
            }

            circle.setRadius(radius);
            rectangle.setDimensions(height, width);
            cout << "The area of the circle is: " << circle.area() << endl;
            cout << "The area of the rectangle is: " << rectangle.area() << endl;
            if (circle == rectangle)
            {
                cout << "The area of the circle is equal to the area of the rectangle.";
            }
            else
                cout << "The area of the circle is not equal to the area of the rectangle.";

            cout << endl << endl;
            break;

        case 4:
            cout << "Enter the radius of the circle: ";
            cin >> radius;

            while (cin.fail())
            {
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(100, '\n');
                cout << endl << "Not a valid input, enter a number: ";
                cin >> radius;
            }

            cout << "Enter the height of the rectangle: ";
            cin >> height;

            while (cin.fail())
            {
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(100, '\n');
                cout << endl << "Not a valid input, enter a number: ";
                cin >> height;
            }

            cout << "Enter the width of the rectangle: ";
            cin >> width;

            while (cin.fail())
            {
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(100, '\n');
                cout << endl << "Not a valid input, enter a number: ";
                cin >> width;
            }

            circle.setRadius(radius);
            rectangle.setDimensions(height, width);
            cout << "The area of the circle is: " << circle.area() << endl;
            cout << "The area of the rectangle is: " << rectangle.area() << endl;
            if (circle > rectangle)
            {
                cout << "The area of the circle is greater than the area of the rectangle.";
            }
            else
                cout << "The area of the rectangle is greater than the circle.";

            cout << endl << endl;
            break;
```

I included case 3 because it is working as expected. Case 4, using almost identical code, is giving an operand error. It seems like it is trying to use the std > instead of the overloaded >. I am not sure how to fix this and any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Attached is an image of the error:

[image: Image of the error when hovering over the operator]

Comment: An overload of `operator>(const CircleType &, const RectangleType &)` only works for an expression of the form `some_circle > some_rectangle`.   To do a comparison `some_rectangle > some_circle` it is necessary to have an `operator>(const RectangleType &, const CircleType &)`   (note the order of arguments is swapped).    Your code does not have the second operator.   Same comment goes for `operator==()`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get the error,
however this tiny example is working
cpp.sh/8excr

may be you should add const qualifier to the area function

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have the const qualifier on the area function of both classes. Is it possibly something else?